# How to schedule custom backup of Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

What is default period or logic ignite cache backup for native persistence.
Is there any way to create custom backup policy ? 
If yes, then how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Ignite persistence doesn't work by backing up the data periodically. It rather stores all the data on disk and modifies it on every write access. So, you can stop the cluster at any point, and it will be able to restore from the same state on the next run.

If you want to know, how fast operation is ensured in such settings, and what guarantees are provided, refer to the following page: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/write-ahead-log

Comment: Sir i know that, what i wanna know is, when all are written to disk and is there any way to configure this.

Comment: The data is continuously written to disk. The only thing you can change is [WAL mode](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.6/docs/write-ahead-log#section-wal-modes). If you set it to BACKGROUND, then updates will be accumulated and flushed to disk in a batch.

Comment: You can also configure checkpointing frequency. Here is documentation on it: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistence-checkpointing#section-checkpointing-tuning

Comment: In FULL_SYNC WAL mode the date is flushed to disk with every write. In LOG_ONLY or BACKGROUND modes the operating system will accumulate and flush its buffers to disk on its own.